# Is it possible to have "null rows" in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using MySQL.  Let's say I have table A, B and C.  Table A is a base table.  Table B and C both have foreign keys to table A.  However I want to pull out the rows so that the output would look something like this.

```
A | B    | C
----------------
1 | 1    | NULL
1 | 2    | NULL
1 | NULL | 1
1 | NULL | 2
2 | 3    | NULL
2 | NULL | 3
```

So when B no longer has any rows left for a certain key the query moves on to C and stop outputting rows for B.  This seems like it should be simple, but I seem to be having trouble coming up with the way it should be done.

Also the title of the question probably doesn't make sense, but I wasn't sure how to best describe the scenario.

Comment: By no means a complete answer, but performing an `OUTER JOIN` from table A to table B will bring back NULL for all columns from B if there's a match in table A but no match in table B.

Comment: as I understood the question, thats not the whole answer. If there is something in B, C should be NULL. If there is nothing in B, look for C.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thinking about it, an OUTER JOIN isn't going to give you the output format you want. Try something like this:

```
SELECT a.id AS A, b.id AS B, NULL AS C
FROM tableA a
INNER JOIN tableB ON a.id = b.fid
UNION
SELECT a.id AS A, NULL AS B, c.id AS C
FROM tableA a
INNER JOIN tableC ON a.id = c.fid
ORDER BY 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely, yes, `LEFT JOIN` is your sharpest knife.

```
SELECT A.*,B.*,C.* FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON A.ID = B.REFID
LEFT JOIN C ON A.ID = C.REFID
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an outer join:

```
select a.id, b.id, c.id
from a
left join b on a.id = b.id
left jon c on a.id = c.id
```